# Inequality by parts $f(n,k)>n \text{ if } 0\leq k\leq n$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose $f$ is a function satisfying:

$$f(n,k)>n \text{ if } 0\leq k\leq n$$

$$f(n,k) \leq n \text{ if } k > n$$

we add the right terms of each inequality and the left terms we have then that

$$
f(n,k)+n \geq f(n,k) +n
$$

the above can be done?

Comment: As stated you have $a+b\ge a+b$.  You need to elaborate.

Comment: Yes, but what are you trying to prove here?

Comment: @UnexpectedConfusion I have the suspicion that by having different inequalities for different ranges of k, it is very suspicious that it can add in both parts!

Comment: To add both equations, their conditions must both be met.  So both $0 \leq k \leq n$ and $n < k$ must be simultaneously true for the new equation to be valid.  Of course, those two conditions are never simultaneously true.

Comment: @EricTowers Not being simultaneously implies that I cannot add them, is that correct?

Comment: You can always add any two things you want.  In this particular case, the first equation is valid for certain pairs of $k$ and $n$ and the second equation is valid for certain pairs of $k$ and $n$.  Their sum is only valid for pairs of $k$ and $n$ that work for both equations.  However, there are no pairs of $k$ and $n$ that work for both equations.

Comment: @EricTowers Thanks for answering, if I understand correctly, it does not matter the conditions of the dominio, the important thing is to always add those that are from the right with the right ones and those that are from the left with those on the left. is that correct?

Comment: @UnexpectedConfusion   The expression you used has a term f(n,k) on both sides of the inequality.  Apparently you intended different (n,k) pairs, but as written they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

First, a comment on the meaning of words:
$$\begin{align} f(n,k) &> n, \quad &0\le k \le n\\f(n,k)&\le n, &k > n\end{align}$$
does not "define" a function. To define a function, you have to specify in some way what value it has at each point in its domain. You have not specified what value $f(n,k)$ is to have. You've places some restrictions on those values in certain conditions, but those restrictions are not enough to determine the value. What you apparently meant is "Suppose $f$ is a function satisfying ...". I.e., we are given that $f$ is some function, and this is just a condition it happens to meet.

Second, "right" and "left" are of no consequence here. You can rewrite the conditions as
$$\begin{align} f(n,k) &> n, \quad &0\le k \le n\\n &\ge f(n,k), &k > n\end{align}$$

But the problem still remains. If the first condition is true, then the second condition is false. So **only one** of these two inequalities is known to be true for a given $k, n$. And since $f(n,k) > n$ and $f(n,k) \le n$ contradict each other, only one of those two statements can be true for any given $n, k$. For example:

- $f(2,1) > 2$, because $0 \le 1 \le 2$. Therefore $f(2,1) \le 2$ is false. No number is both $> 2$ and $\le 2$.
- $f(3,4) \le 3$, because $4 > 3$. It is not true that $f(3,4) > 3$, since that contradicts $f(3,4) \le 3$.

So even though you can turn the inequalities to line up as you wanted, it does not allow you to add them together, because for any given $n,k$ *only one of the two inequalities is true*.

Also, if $a > b$ and $c \ge d$, then we can say that $a + c > b + d$, not just $a + c \ge b + d$. Because even if $c = d$, we still get a strict inequality from $a > b$. And if it were possible to add the two together as you wanted, you would get
$$f(n, k) + n > f(n, k) + n$$
which claims that a value is strictly greater than itself. That alone should tip you off that something is seriously wrong here. Indeed even with your weaker statement, it is clear that $f(n, k) + n \ge f(n, k) + n$ is *always* true, regardless of what $f(n,k)$ is, since the two sides are the same. But one can easily invent functions $f$ for which the original conditions are false.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and dedication to clarify these doubts. I really appreciate the detail of your explanation.